# "There would need to be excavation down from the street"

Tags: phrase-usage

It looks strange to me. I think it'd be better as "There would need to be excavated down from the street".

Isn't there any problem with this sentence?

Comment: Try replacing *would need to be* with *is* and it might be clearer to see that *excavation* is correct. (*There is excavated* doesn't make any sense. *There is excavation* does.)

Comment: "There" is not a suitable object for "to be excavated", unfortunately. That situation requires a noun, e.g. "*the hillside* would need to be excavated for the building's foundations".

Answer (score 1):

In the quoted sentence, *there* is a [dummy pronoun](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/it-and-there) which serves as the subject of *needs*. *Would* is a modal verb indicating the conditional *[irrealis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood#Conditional)* mood. The infinitive phrase *to be excavation down from the street* is the direct object.

Within that phrase, *excavation* is the [predicate nominative](http://classroom.synonym.com/distinguishing-between-direct-objects-predicate-nominatives-3725.html) of *to be*, which must be a noun or pronoun. One would naturally expect the noun (*excavation*) or gerund (*excavating*) form. The participle form *excavated* might be understood in context, it is not commonly used as a substantive, and would look strange out of context.

We could also use *excavated* if we want to describe the condition of the place down from the street, as opposed to an activity there, but I would use the dummy pronoun *it* instead of *there*:

Substituting *must be* for *needs to be*, or even *is* as Damkerng T notes, may help "sound out" the preferable form.

> There needs to be excavation.
>
> There must be excavation.
>
> It needs to be excavated.
>
> It must be excavated.

Answer (score 0):

"There need to be" should be followed by a noun in singular or plural form. if the noun is singular, you should use "There needs to be", for plural, it should be "There need to be". for more information, refer to the link 
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Should_you_say_there_need_be_or_there_need_to_be?#slide=1